# Where to get the Model for EdgeBoxes in OpenCV Python

Tags: opencv, object-detection, edge-detection

The link below provides the python implementation for edgeboxes:
https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/96ea9a0d8a2dee4ec97ebdec8f79f3c8a24de3b0/modules/ximgproc/samples/edgeboxes_demo.py

However, I do not understand this part:

```
model = sys.argv[1]
```

I want to know from where can I get this model?

Answer (score 1):

```
model = sys.argv[1]
```

means that the first argument passed when you call this script from shell it's the model.

```
Usage:
  edgeboxes_demo.py [<model>] [<input_image>]
```

You can use the example model provided in the opencv extra [repository](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_extra/blob/master/testdata/cv/ximgproc/model.yml.gz)